# Timestamps in Stata

Tags: time, format, stata

I am looking to replace a time stamp from 00:00:00 to 23:59:59.

Stata still shows the timestamp as 00:00:00

```
replace time_out = mdyhms(month(date), day(date), year(date), hh(23), mm(59), ss(59)) 

format time_out %tc
```

The storage type is double. It was created by this command:

```
gen time = clock(ptime, "hm")
format time %tc
```

Comment: You need to tell us how the variable was `generate`d and what is its variable or storage type.

Comment: No reproducible example. How does `time_out` relate to `time`? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for guidance.

Comment: `gen time = ` would **not** create a `double` unless you have `set type double`.

Answer (score 0):

I am as yet unable to follow your problem. This toy example shows that changing to show 23:59:59 is perfectly possible.

```
. clear

. set obs 1
Number of observations (_N) was 0, now 1.

. gen double time = clock("00:00", "hm")

. format time %tc

. list

     +--------------------+
     |               time |
     |--------------------|
  1. | 01jan1960 00:00:00 |
     +--------------------+


. replace time = clock("23:59:59", "hms")
(1 real change made)

. list

     +--------------------+
     |               time |
     |--------------------|
  1. | 01jan1960 23:59:59 |
     +--------------------+
```

Comment: I did set type double but that didn't help.

Comment: Still no reproducible example from you to discuss.